# Does it follow that if gcd$(x,6)=1$ and $n \ge 4$, then $x[3^{n-1}a + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i})]$ cannot have the same form?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, proof-writing, infinite-descent

**Let:**

- $n\ge 4, x, a, b$ be integers
- gcd$(c,d)$ be the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $c$ and $d$
- gcd$(x,6)=1$
- $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ be positive integers
- $q_1, q_2, \dots, q_n$ be positive integers
- $P_i = \sum\limits_{k=1}^i p_k$
- $Q_i = \sum\limits_{k=1}^i q_k$

**Question**:

It seems to me that for a large enough $n$,  $x[3^{n-1}a + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i})]$ cannot have the form: $3^{n-1}b + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{Q_i})$.

I am not clear how to prove this.  Here's my thinking:

- I suspect that the product of $x$ and  $3^{n-1}a + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i})$
  cannot have this form for $n \ge 4$.
- I suspect the product can have this form when $n=2$.
- I have found that the product can have this form when $x$ is a power of $2$ such as $1, 2, 4, \dots$

Could someone help me to find an argument to show that the product cannot have this form, a counter example to show that it can, or an explanation for why the problem is difficult to resolve one way or the other.

---

**Edit:**

Note: Thanks to John Omielan for catching a mistake in my edit.  I have updated this edit.

I believe that I have found a counter example when there exists integers $m,b$ where $x = 2^m + 3^{n-1}b$.

Let:

- $T = 3^{n-1}a + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i})$

Then:
$$xT = 3^{n-1}(a2^m+bT) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i+m})$$

Would this be the only counter example?  If no such $b$ exists for any value $m$, does that imply that the product would not have the form?

---

**Edit 2:**

Note:  I have updated the detail of the problem to clarify that in the form $a$ means any integer.  From John's comment, it becomes clear that this opens up the number of counter examples beyond the one in edit 1.

Comment: The sequence of $p$'s seem to magically appear from nowhere. Can you tell us more about them ?

So we have a number of the form $3^{n-1}a + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i})$ ... & we multiply it by $x$ ... and then try to express this in the form $3^{n-1}a + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{\color{red}{Q}_i})$ ... do we need $P$'s and $Q$'s to be the same ?

Comment: The $P_i$ are sums of $p_k$  where each $p_k$ is a positive integer.  So that $P_[$ divides $P_2$ for example.

Comment: @LarryFreeman With your stated counter-example, I get $xT = (2^m)T + (3^{n-1}b)T$. With the first term, $(2^m)T = 2^m(3^{n-1}a + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i})) = 3^{n-1}a(2^m) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i + m})$. This gives $xT = 3^{n-1}a(2^m) + (3^{n-1}b)T + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i + m})$ which simplifies to $xT = 3^{n-1}(a2^m + bT) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{P_i + m})$. Thus, the second terms match but the first term do not so, in general, will have different values. Please double check to see if there's a typo in your $x$ definition or a mistake in your algebra.

Comment: @LarryFreeman You're welcome. To ping me, please use "@", as I just happened to check here again. Also, your edit is still not quite correct. As my comment shows, the "$a$" factor should be on the right of "(", i.e., your "$3^{n-1}a(2^m+bT)$" should be "$3^{n-1}(a2^m+bT)$". Also, your question isn't clear. Your example shows the form for $xT$ can be $2^{n-1}c + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{Q_i})$ for some $c$, & $Q_i$ which are a sum of positive $q_j$. If so, I suspect this more general form has additional counter-examples. Please clarify if $a$ in your $xT$ form is different from that in $T$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thanks!  I fixed it..  I updated the form to use $b$ to make it clear that $a$ is different.  Great point.  The more I think about it, the more it is clear that with this broad definition of $a$, there will be more counter examples.

Comment: @LarryFreeman You're welcome. However, you still have $2^{P_i}$ in both cases, but your example shows they can be different. This is what Donald originally asked about, & I did as well. In general, apart from cases where a variable has a clear limited scope, e.g., $i$, $j$, $k$ as index variables in a summation or product, you should avoid using the same variable to mean different things in various parts of your text and, especially, within the same statement. I understand your "$P_i$" are meant to be generic, & different in $xT$, but reusing this can cause people to think they're the same.

Comment: Very good point.  I will update to make this clearer.  I have been finding it challenging to speak about the "form" of a number.  I think it makes sense to use a different variable to avoid ambiguity.  I will update.